# Are there masculine equivalents to わよ

Tags: sentence-final-particles

I have come across わよ　as a sentence ending particle with a feminine feel, but are there any masculine equivalents?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing would be ぞ, while よ is their neutral equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

ぜ seems to fit.

- いいわよ - いいぜ
- できたわよ - できたぜ